# How to use git update-index --assume-unchanged <file> with pathspec?

Tags: bash, git

I have a bunch of auto-generated files I would like to temporarily hide/ignore from my git. I tried this:

`git update-index --assume-unchanged '*.gen.*'`

but I'm getting a fatal error. Is there a solution to this? Or must I do this file by file?

Comment: Use `git ls-files` or any other command (perhaps just a shell) to generate the list of matching files, and then run `git update-index --assume-unchanged` on that list of files. In shell script that's `git update-index --assume-unchanged $(git ls-files -m '*.gen.*')`, for instance. I use `-m` here on the assumption that we don't need to set the flag for files that aren't already in Git's index or match the working tree copy.

Comment: Note, however, that storing *generated* files in Git is usually a sign that you're doing something wrong. There are some exceptions to this rule, but they are less common than people use them. :-)

Comment: I couldn't agree more but unfortunately, I don't have much leverage on the structure of the code base :)

Comment: Have you read [the Git FAQ entry](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files) explaining that you can't ignore tracked files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shorter form should work as well :

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged $(git ls-files -m '**/*.gen.*')
```

for the reverse :

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged $(git ls-files -v '**/*.gen.*' | grep -Po '^[[:lower:]]+\s+\K.*')
```

Comment: Nice one! that works. What about the reverse? i.e `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged`

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion from [@torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) I came up with these commands:

#### Hide `.gen.` files

`git status -s | grep '.gen.' | cut -c 4- | xargs -I FILE git update-index --assume-unchanged FILE`

- `git status -s` list files in [short format](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#Documentation/git-status.txt---short)
- `grep '.gen.'` filter list to files containing `.gen.` anywhere in the path
- `cut -c 4-` cut the start of each string to remove the `M`
- `xargs -I FILE git update-index --assume-unchanged FILE` loops through each of the files and executes the git command

#### List ignored files

`git ls-files -v | grep "^[a-z]"`

#### Unhide all files

`git ls-files -v | grep "^[a-z]" | cut -c 3- | xargs -I FILE git update-index --no-assume-unchanged FILE`

This won't work for files that are not yet in the repo but it is enough for my use case.